# How to set textView 100% height of parent

Tags: autolayout, storyboard, interface-builder

I need to make the tv stretch to 100% of the height of the parent view. If I add an upper and lower constraint - the parent view narrows to the size of the textview

[image]
[image]

I tried to align the vertical center and make the height equal - the same problem

Comment: Add Top/Leading/Trailing/Bottom constraints.

Comment: As @DonMag says you have to set those constraints to all 4 sides. Then play around with Content resistance and content compression priorities to ensure the views size appropriatley.